# show that f(x)=0 has no positive solution if f(0)=0

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be twice differentiable function on $\mathbb R$. Given that $f''(x)>0,\; \forall x \in \mathbb R$, how to show that $f(x)=0$ has no positive solution if $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)>0$?

Comment: Sounds like HW.  Hint:  MVT.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f'>0$, $f$ is *strictly* increasing, so if $f(0)=0$, you will have $f>0$ if $x>0$ and $f<0$ if $x<0$. There is no need to consider the second derivative.

---

**ADD** If you really meant that $f'(0)>0$ only, then you will have to use that $f''>0$. This means the first derivative is strictly increasing, that is, $f$ is convex (or concave up) so from $f'(0)>0$ and $f(0)=0$ you must conclude $f$ will lie above the $x$ axis for $x>0$.

Comment: Yes, you do, since we are given that f'(0) > 0,  not f'(x) for all x.

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn The post says "f^'(x)>0".

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn Although presumably the OP presumably meant that, yes.-

Comment: @GitGud He wrote $f(0)=0$, not $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Right.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir Peter Tamaroff

Comment: @UDAYREDDY You're welcome, but I am no sir.